# Converting a for loop into Task.Parallel.For

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I have a procedure **bool IsExistImage(int i)** . the task of the procedure to detect an image and return bool whether it exist or not.

i have a PDF of 100+ pages which i split and send only the file name through the method. file names are actually the pagenumber of the main PDF file. like 1,2,3,...,125,..

after detecting the image, my method correctly save the list of pages. For that i used this code:

```
ArrayList array1 = new ArrayList();
for(int i=1;i<pdf.length;i++)
{
   if(isExistImage(i))
   {
       array1.add(i);
   }
}
```

This process runs for more than 1 hours(obviously for the internal works in isExistImage() method.). I can assure you, that no object/variable are global out side the method scope.

So, to shorten the time, I used Task.Parallel For loop. here is what i did :

```
System.Threading.Tasks,Parallel.For(1,pdf.Length,i =>
{
    if(isExistImage(i))
        array1.Add(i);
}
```

But this is not working properly. Sometimes the image detection is right. But most of the time its wrong. When i use non parallel for loop, then it's always right.

I am not understanding what is the problem here. what should i apply here. Is there any technique i am missing?

Comment: What does the `isExistImage` method do? You should use a `List<int>` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: [Potential Pitfalls in Data and Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As @Johnbot said, use a generic collection. Also, what type of collection is pdf?

Comment: I have used. but no result.
Pdf is another arraylist, containing file names like 1,2,3,4,....,25,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `ArrayList` (and most other .Net collections) is not thread-safe.

There are several ways to fix this, but I think that in this case, the best option is to use PLINQ:

```
List<int> pagesWithImages = ParallelEnumerable.Range(1, pdf.Length)
    .Where(i => isExistImage(i))
    .ToList();
```

This will use multiple threads to call the (weirdly named) `isExistImage` method, which is exactly what you want, and then return a `List<int>` containing the indexes that matched the condition.

The returned list won't be sorted. If you want that, add `AsOrdered()` before the `Where()`.

BTW, you really shouldn't be using `ArrayList`. If you want a list of integers, use `List<int>`.

Comment: I have tried generic List<int>. But no positive result. 
isExistImage() returns bool. not Int.
why the name is weird?

Comment: Just switching from `ArrayList` to `List<int>` won't help, because `List<int>` also isn't thread-safe. I realize that it returns bool, that's why I suggested that you use PLINQ `Where`, have you tried that? And the name is weird, because it's not gramatically correct.

Comment: I realize later that you actually realized. Then I implemented PLINQ as you suggested. Testing is going on. In one case, it worked. I will confirm it. 
I am not sure about the grammatical incorrectness. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

1. ArrayList isn't thread safe; look into concurrent collections [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. is isExistImage thread safe? I.e. are you locking before updating any member variables??

Comment: sorry for marking negative. that was a mistake. you may edit the answer then i can up vote this.